Upper bounds for the heights $H(\alpha + \beta)$ and $H(\alpha \beta)$ , of algebraic numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$
I found a curious definition in a book that I am reading and I am stuck trying to solve one exercise
Definition The height of a polynomial $P(x) = p_n x^n + \cdots + p_1 x + p_0$ is the maximum of the absolute values of its coefficients, $H(P) = \max_{0 \leq k \leq n} |p_k|$.
The height $H(\alpha)$ of an algebraic number $\alpha$ is the height of its minimal polynomial from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, whose coefficients do not possess a non-trivial common divisor (a so-called primitive polynomial)
Exercise:
Establish bounds for the heights $H(\alpha + \beta)$ and $H(\alpha \beta)$ from above, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic numbers, by means of $\deg \alpha$, $\deg \beta$, $H(\alpha)$, and $H(\beta)$.
I guess I can use that for  $\alpha$ and $\beta$  two algebraic numbers, $\alpha + \beta$, $\alpha - \beta$, $\alpha \beta$, and $\alpha / \beta$ (if $\beta \ne 0$) are algebraic, each of degree not more than the product of degrees of $\alpha$ and of $\beta$.  But I am clueless what to do with this since I must relate  the coefficients of the various polynomials  How would you solve it?

Note: The only result in the section of the book is the following lemma that might or not be useful for this
Lemma 6.6:
Let $G$ be a symmetric polynomial from the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ of $n$ variables and $s_1 = x_1 + \cdots + x_n$, $s_2 = x_1 x_2 + \cdots + x_{n-1} x_n$, $\dots$, $s_n = x_1 \cdots x_n$, the elementary symmetric polynomials. Then there exists a polynomial $F \in \mathbb{Z}[y_1, \dots, y_n]$ of degree at most $\deg G$ such that
$F(s_1, s_2, \dots, s_n) = G(x_1, \dots, x_n)$.
This is exercise 6.6 on this book https://pdfupload.io/docs/735f9678

Do you know how to find a polynomial that vanish at $\alpha+\beta$ given the minimal polynomials of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

@jjagmath Not really

Then how do you know that $\alpha + \beta$ is algebraic?

@jjagmath It is a theorem in the book, which says that the sum of algebraic numbers is algebraic

Ok, I was trying to be subtle. Go to that proof that the sum is algebraic and see if you can  find something about a polynomial that vanish at $\alpha + \beta$.

@jjagmath They use a lemma but I don't see any explicit construaction of such a polynomial in the proof either. The proof is different (lemma 6.3 and theorem 6.1)
